# Stackoverflow iGoogle Gadget

Tags: discussion, google

A couple of weeks ago, I created a very simple Stack Overflow iGoogle Gadget. If anyone's interested, here's the URL for adding it: [*click*](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?hl=en&url=files.getdropbox.com%2Fu%2F10936%2FgadgetHosting%2FstackoverflowProfile%2Fprod%2Fstackoverflow.xml)

Comments are welcome.

Comment: Now that iGoogle is on its way out, this is not only off-topic, but also too localized.

Comment: @PopularDemand Sure, but couldn't know that ~3 years ago :)

Comment: Not blaming you, just explaining my vote for those who followed me.

Answer (score 1):

I added it and put in my UserName but it got stuck on "Loading..."

I was also kind of wondering why there wasn't any sort of authentication going on. If I wanted to, I could have my very own Jon Skeet stalker rep-stalker gadget on my page. Overall I don't think this is major.

Comment: "stock" should be "stuck," I'm assuming :)

Comment: Looks like you need to use your #, not your name.

Comment: That works Rich

Comment: Yes you have to use your name, and yes, you could have your own Jon Skeet rep-gadget on your page, if you like so :) I don't think this would bring you that much value ;) but anyway